# DSS(Darwin Streaming Server) install failed on OS X10.10

Tags: macos, darwin

I want to build a Darwin Streaming Server on my mac for iOS development test. But after taking the following steps which I searched from google, it fails all the time.

**Method 1:**

- Download from http://dss.macosforge.org/ ->Mac OS X Install -> Streaming Server;
- Install the dmg;
- It tries to open http://127.0.0.1:1220/ but fails with "This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

**Method 2:**

- Download the source code of 6.0.3 version;
- $ tar xvf DarwinStreamingSrvr6.0.3-Source.tar
- $ cd DarwinStreamingSrvr6.0.3-Source
- $ wget http://www.abrahamsson.com/dss-6.0.3.patch
- $ patch -p0 < dss-6.0.3.patch
- $ ./Buildit

Then, it fails with the following words.

> ### Darwin Streaming Server
>
> I don't know your platform. I'll assume this is a Linux x86 platform.
>   Please edit the BuildServer script & PlatformHeader.h to add your platform.
>   Building for Darwin.x86_64 with gcc
>   xcodebuild DarwinStreamingServer
>
> === BUILD LIBRARY TARGET AtomicLib (Library) OF PROJECT StreamingServer WITH CONFIGURATION Development ===
>
> Check dependencies
>   Jam is deprecated and has been removed; targets that use Jam must be upgraded to native targets. For more information on doing this, consult the Xcode documentation.
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       Check dependencies
>   (1 failure)"

- I tried to run `./Install`, it showed me

> Unable to perform install
>   You must be logged in as root to install Darwin Streaming Server

and I don't know what to do now.

PS: I've installed Xcode on my mac and didn't find any available document about Darwin Streaming Server, or I missed it?

Hope for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I solved this issue with the help of my friend.
Here's the steps of solution.

- I've given up compiling and building on my own and downloaded the dmg file.(version 6.0.3)
- Install the dmg as directions.
- Then, go to `/usr/sbin` in terminal and find `streamingadminserver.pl`  and  `QuickTimeStreamingServer`.
- Run them.
- Check if they're running with `ps aux|grep streaming`.
- Open `http://localhost:1220/parse_xml.cgi` in Safari or Chrome. It will show some textfield and a button.
- However, there's no words at all ! Go to `/Library/QuickTimeStreaming/AdminHtml` and edit `setup_assistant2.html`.
- Find line 333 and change it from `return "$message{$name}";` to `return $name;`.
- Then it shows some understandable words, though not exact words.

Till now, it can be partly work. However, in some steps I mentioned above, for example, html editing step, I really don't know why the words just don't show and just have a try.

Save the exact steps I did here for memory. It will be wonderful if it can help anyone or anyone have some good idea about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Lilac, I am not able to find ** return "$message{$name}"; ** in setup_assistant2.html. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SouravGupta Don't worry about it. It isn't rather matter if you can find the line or not. I've lost most of the details in my mind since it's been a long time, but I remember that I changed that line of code just to get rid of the unreadable words in website. Maybe you don't need the step at all. Just try to find the key point, forget about the code line. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Calios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31041950) and [Jessica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42167654), thank you for your answers. I'm running using OS Windows 7 and installing DSS 5.5.5 for windows, and I also meet the condition same as with you.

However, after I followed your instructions, it's not close enough with our needs, because the button will lose meaning in presentation.

So I started digging more information from another articles, and I found interesting perception from a developer at [this article](https://sathisharthars.com/2014/01/08/configuring-audiovideo-streaming-server-in-linux/). He said the following:

> Maybe this has something to do with the perl script which generates the web sites?*

So starting from Jens's perception, I tried to downgrade my Perl Script from version 5.26 to 5.8. This resolved my problem, the interface displays correctly as in the DSS Tutorial.

Right now I'm still working on testing the DSS function

I hope this solution will help others.

Answer (score 0):

QTSS/DSS Web Admin 6.0.3 requires Perl version 5.16 and earlier. OS X 10.11 El Capitan installs both Perl versions 5.16 and 5.18, but it defaults to using Perl version 5.18.

In order to run QTSS/DSS Web Admin in OS X 10.11 El Capitan, you need to examine each of the Perl script (`.pl`) within the `AdminHtml` folder and change the line `#!/usr/bin/perl` to `#!/usr/bin/perl5.16`.