# Darwin Streaming Server install problems os x

Tags: macos, perl, darwin

My problem is the same as the one mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993243/dssdarwin-streaming-server-install-failed-on-os-x10-10/31041950#31041950) answer. I've been trying to understand the code and this is what I learned:

It is failing in the file *parse_xml.cgi*, tries to get messages (`return $message{$name}`) from a file named *messages* (located in the html_en directory).
The $messages value comes from the method `GetMessageHash` in file *adminprotocol-lib.pl*:

```
sub GetMessageHash
{
   return $ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"}
}
```

The `$ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"}` is set in the file *streamingadminserver.pl*:

```
$ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"} = $messages{"en"}
```

I dont know anything about Perl so I have no idea of what the problem can be, for what I saw `$messages{"en"}` has the correct value (if I do `print($messages{"en"}{'SunStr'}` I get the value "Sun")).

However, if I try   to do `print($ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"}{'SunStr'}` I get nothing. Seems like `$ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"}` is not set

I tried this simple example and it worked fine:

```
$ENV{"HELLO"} = "hello";
print($ENV{"HELLO"});
```

and it works fine, prints "hello".

Any idea of what the problem can be?

Comment: Darwin Streaming Server is functionally obsolete. There have been no new releases since 2007! I'd avoid using it for any new projects.

Comment: You are right, I still needed to try because I haven't found many options for what I need (an open source server able to stream mp4 over RTSP). If I wanted to use it i'd need to adapt some stuff (and dedicate some time to learn Perl) so I guess I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$messages{"en"}` is a **[HashRef](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)**: A pointer to some memory address holding a key-value-store. You could even print the associated memory address:

```
perl -le 'my $hashref = {}; print $hashref;'
HASH(0x1548e78)
```

0x1548e78 is the address, but it's only valid within the same running process. Re-run the sample command and you'll get different addresses each time.

*HASH(0x1548e78)* is also just a human-readable representation of the real stored value. Setting `$hashref2="HASH(0x1548e78)";` won't create a real reference, just a copy of the human-readable string.

You could easily proof this theory using `print $ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"}` in both script.

[Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) is typically used to show the contents of the referenced hash (memory location):

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($messages{"en"});
# or 
print Dumper($ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"});
```

This will also show if the pointer/reference could be dereferenced in both scripts.

The solution for your problem is probably passing the value instead of the HashRef:

```
$ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_SUN"} = $messages{"en"}->{SunStr};
```

Best Practice is using a -> between both keys. The " or ' quotes for the key also [optional if the key is a plain word](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Not-so-symbolic-references).

But passing everything through environment variables feels wrong. They might not be able to hold references on OSX (I don't know). You might want to extract the string storage to a include file and load it via *[require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)*.

See http://www.perlmaven.com/ or http://learn.perl.org for more about Perl.

Answer (score -1):

fix code:

```
$$ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"} = $messages{"en"};

sub GetMessageHash
{
   return $$ENV{"QTSSADMINSERVER_EN_MESSAGEHASH"};
}
```

ref:
https://github.com/guangbin79/dss6.0.3-linux-patch